# How can I place a text box in front of a page border in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm doing an assignment for someone where I need to recreate the styling of the article below.  One of the things I'm trying to recreate is the "About the authors" text-box on the left side of the page, where the box is overlaying the page border.

When I try to do this in Word, the page border shows up on top of the text box.

- I tried clicking "Bring to front" while having the text box selected but it didn't work.
- I'm using Office 365, so it's the current version of Word.
- In the image below the page border color is not the same as the text box color, even though they do look very similar when you're zoomed out.

[image]

Comment: Look at it in print preview.  It's possible that what you're seeing is a layout guide that isn't actually part of the page.  If not, it would be helpful to add a screenshot of the Word version.  How is that page border created/defined as a page element?

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the help, I just figured it out and posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got the answer from [here](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BordersRibbon.htm): you need to go to Design → Page Borders → Page Border → Options and then disable the "Always display in front" checkbox.

[image]